# C# ListBox Does Not Allow Drag & Drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox

I am not able to drag and drop files into my listbox.  I have set the AllowDrop property to true and added the following code but the cursor is a circle with the line through the middle and does not allow me to drop files:

```
public List<string> files = new List<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragDrop);
        this.listBox1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragEnter);
    }



    private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s[i]));
                files.Add(s[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've done this successfully on another project, the only difference is I am now using Visual Studio 2017.  Any ideas as to why this is not working?

Comment: I just realized I needed to add [STAThread] to my Program.cs file to allow this to work.

Comment: See my article [Drag-and-Drop ListBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36412/Drag-and-Drop-ListBox) at Code Project. You can also download and implementation there.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I needed to add [STAThread] to my Program.cs file to allow this to work